# Faster way than concatenate of combining multiple cv2 images (numpy arrays) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I have 100 small images which I want to combine into one large (10x10) grid image for display with imshow. Each image (as a numpy array) is within the variable of a cell object. At the moment I'm using concatenate to first create vertical strips then using concatenate to connect all of those strips but it seems kinda clunky. Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I should be able to just create a numpy array the size of the final image (800 x 600) then plop each image in, but it seems to be beyond my ability to wrap my head around the syntax.

```
def stackImages(im1, im2, axisToStack):
    newImage = np.concatenate((im1, im2), axis = axisToStack)
    return newImage

def compileCells():
    #Make a list of strips
    strips = [(np.zeros((0,cellWidth,3), np.uint8)) for i in range(numberOfCells)]

    for x in range(numberOfCells):
        for i in range(numberOfCells):
            strips[x] = stackImages(cellArray[i+(x*numberOfCells)].image, strips[x], 0)

    display = strips[0]
    for c in range(1,numberOfCells):
        display = stackImages(strips[c], display, 1)
    return display
```

Comment: `concatenate` will accept a long list of arrays, not just 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying arrays can be a real speed killer when working with NumPy.  Every time
`np.concatenate` is called, space for a new array is allocated, and all the old
data is copied into the new array.  A way to make your code faster is to reduce
the amount of copying.

So as you suggested, the faster way is to allocate space for the final array,
`display` from the very the beginning:

```
display = np.empty((cellHeight*nrows, cellWidth*ncols, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

and then copy the data from `cellArray` into `display` just once:

```
for i, j in IT.product(range(nrows), range(ncols)):
    arr = cellArray[i*ncols+j].image  
    x, y = i*cellHeight, j*cellWidth
    display[x:x+cellHeight, y:y+cellWidth, :] = arr
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as IT

def compileCells(cellArray, nrows, ncols, cellHeight, cellWidth):
    display = np.empty((cellHeight*nrows, cellWidth*ncols, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i, j in IT.product(range(nrows), range(ncols)):
        # arr = cellArray[i*ncols+j].image  # you may need this
        arr = cellArray[i*ncols+j]          # my simplified cellArray uses this
        x, y = i*cellHeight, j*cellWidth
        display[x:x+cellHeight, y:y+cellWidth, :] = arr
    return display

cellHeight, cellWidth = 80, 60
nrows = ncols = numberOfCells = 10

cellArray = [np.full((cellHeight, cellWidth, 3), i) 
             for i in np.linspace(0, 255, nrows*ncols)]
display = compileCells(cellArray, nrows, ncols, cellHeight, cellWidth)
plt.imshow(display)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Note, your code implies that `cellArray` is a list of objects whose `image`
attributes are NumPy arrays. To make the example code above runnable and simple(r),
I've defined `cellArray` above to be a list of NumPy arrays. 
You may need to uncomment

```
# arr = cellArray[i*ncols+j].image
```

and comment out

```
arr = cellArray[i*ncols+j]
```

to fit your definition of `cellArray`.

---

Let's compare the amount of copying done by the two approaches:

Using the original approach, if we say that an image array has size 1, then to build a `strip` requires
allocating arrays of size 1, 2, ..., 10. So one strip requires allocating arrays
of total size 1+2+...+10 = 10(11)/2 = 55. To build `display` requires allocating
arrays of total size 55(1+2+..+10) = 55*55 = 3025. Each allocation of space is
accompanied by a copy operation. The amount of copying grows **quadratically** with the number of cells in the final array.

In contrast, if we allocate space for the final `display` just once, then we
only need to allocate  of total size 10*10 = 100. Here, the amount of copying grows **linearly** with the number of cells.

Comment: Wow thanks for the in-depth comment and solution. I really appreciate it!