# Condense and combine images in python

Tags: python, image, data-visualization

I have 100 TIF images of scanned sediment core material. I need to visually display these images in a way that allows me to display data that corresponds to the core by depth. An example of a core image:[Sediment Core 507.2-509.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R125z.jpg)

An example of what I'm trying to visualize:[Core Chart, Hull et al. 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxltN.png)

I've been hunting around for an answer and this (below) was the closest but if there's a package that can help with this, I'd be grateful.

[Faster way than concatenate of combining multiple cv2 images (numpy arrays) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956677/faster-way-than-concatenate-of-combining-multiple-cv2-images-numpy-arrays-in-p)

Comment: Errr... we are programmers, not geologists How do we go from one brown column to 2 columns with red bits, please? Maybe you could add a diagram showing where the first few of your 100 TIFFs end up in the result. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mark, that photo was just an example of what a core photo looks like, as SE wouldnt let me upload my own core photos. Basically I just need to know if there is a way to stitch photos together while keeping their numerical depth data for plotting purposes, like in the Hull et al. image I attached.